# Material Reflection: Creating an Optical Filter in Cycles

Tags: texturing, materials

I am very new to Blender and am using it to create images for a new kind of solar energy device.  However, one of the pieces of this device is an optical filter: i.e. it is a square plane that reflects ONLY the red light.  Thus, blue light can pass through.

My question to the wonderful people on Blender Stack Exchange: is there any way of creating a material that reflects only a small portion of the visible light?  I realize that this is a very niche topic, but any ideas or advice you may have will be much appreciated!

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would something like this work?  The Glossy reflects only red and the Transparent Shader allows all the Green/Blue to pass.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah!  This is perfect, thank you so much for your help -- it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

A different way to think about this is to make the light source have different colors for glossy rays and for transmission:

In this example direct rays will be white, reflected will be red and transmited will be blue.

The plane in the middle has a simple glass shader.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help in this, this is another great way to accomplish this.